# Cordova iOS platform version table

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-ios, cordova-android

i'm trying to map every cordova-version with its supported iOS version but in the official documentation there's no a table like in for the Android tab.

So i need to know foreach cordova-ios version, which is the range of iOS version supported.

For now i mapped only the Android releases version.
At the end, if someone is interested, i'll publish the mapper that will contains: phonegap-builder, cordova-cli, cordova-android, cordova-ios, ios and android version mapped with their dependencies.

Many thanks in advance.

Simon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From newer to older:

Cordova iOS 4.4.0+ supports iOS 9+

Cordova iOS 4.0.0+ supports iOS 8+

Cordova iOS 3.4.1+ supports iOS 6+

Comment: Hi jcesarmobile,
thanks for reply. 

ok this can be helpful but ... there's no a superior limit for each ios version supported by cordova-ios platform.

example: cordova-ios 4.4.0 support ios version from X to Y 
the problem is that in the official doc. isn't reported the maximum ios version supported by a platform. Instead, the android version is very detailed :(

Comment: @SimoneCampagna that really depends on what do you mean by "support". Any Cordova app created with Cordova iOS 3.4.1 or newer will work in iOS 11 as long as you compile it with Xcode 8. When using Xcode 8 you compile the app with iOS 10 SDK and iOS 10 SDK apps work in a compatibility mode on iOS 11 devices. If you want to know which Cordova iOS uses iOS 11 SDK, then there is no answer for that, Cordova iOS can be used with Xcode 8 and Xcode 9 and that is what determine the iOS SDK used. But to use Xcode 9 you need Cordova iOS 4.5.4 as it fixes some Xcode 9 bugs.

Comment: The same happens with Cordova Android, so on the table you mention the max versions are "wrong". I have apps created with cordova-android 2.x.x and they still work on Android 7 devices and probably Android 8 too (I don't have one to test). Cordova Android doesn't really set the max sdk anywhere, just the min sdk and the target sdk. So that table probably refers to the target sdk used in that version. But same way as on iOS, the apps work on a compatibility mode on greater OS versions. As for iOS the SDK used depends on the Xcode version used to build the app, it can't be documented.

Comment: Hi jcesarmobile, yes i mean a table that can be resume for each cordova version min / max sdk support version; event if i think that can be useless too due to the plugins sdk limit versions. 

Many many thanks :)

Comment: Where did this table come from? Is there a source you could provide?

Comment: From the release blog posts and checking cordova-ios source code, and being a contributor also helps